# How does the z-index property really work?

Tags: html, css, z-index

How does `z-index` actually work?
Does it function on elements with no specified `position`?
Does it favor elements (i.e. make them on top) that have a specified `position`?

Do the numbers have to be negative like this?

```
<div style='z-index:-2;'>below</div>
<div style='z-index:-1;'>less below</div>
<div style='z-index:0;'>on top</div>
```

Or not? Would all positive numbers (in increasing value) end up with the last being on the top, the middle in the middle, and the first on the bottom?

Comment: *I'm learning from W3Schools, and their lesson on this is so confusing! :(*. Try a more reputable source, such as MDN.

Comment: read that [article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), it will give some trick about z-index, and explain why it's doesnt works when parents has properties like opacity, transform...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index : *"Only works on positioned elements(position: absolute;, position: relative; or position: fixed;)."* More in depth explanation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index.

Comment: This post on FreeCodeCamp is very lucid and simple. I would highly recommend going through it. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Both negative and positive integers are allowed.**

**The position must be set on the element.**

Before I get into those details, though, let me explain `z-index` from the ground up.

Every webpage is made up of what are called stacking contexts. You can think of these as, quite literally, a stack of elements. The z-index property determines the order of items in each stack, with higher z-index being placed further up.

All pages begin with a root stacking context, which builds from the root element (as you'd expect). But more stacking contexts can be created in a number of ways. One way is an absolutely positioned div; its children will be in a new stacking context.

[The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) lists all of the instances that create a new stacking context. As others have stated, this includes *explicitly* positioned elements and will soon include elements that aren't completely opaque.

As I said before, `z-index` only takes effect if you *explicitly* set the position of the element. This means setting it to be `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`. This is best shown through example, I think.

[In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gYaVF/), we'd expect the blue div to be on top of the grey one given its z-index, right? But, as you can see, it's on the bottom. This is, of course, because we haven't set its position. [Once we do that](http://jsfiddle.net/zTR5Q/) it displays as we'd expect. **Again, you must set the position**.

The specs also tell us that negative values are fine. With that said, you don't *need* to use negative values. It's perfectly fine to use positive integers, too. The default `z-index` value for an element is 0.

For the record, w3schools is a notoriously unreliable source for learning. While it can be a quick and convenient resource, there are lots of gaps in their information, and at times even wrong information. I recommend you to use more reliable sources like the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), and also [the specs themselves](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html).

Comment: Does it require a `position` to be set?

Comment: Yep. It's got to be `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`.

Comment: Look here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/ `Although z-index is not a difficult property to understand, due to false assumptions it can cause confusion for beginning developers. This confusion occurs because z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative.`

Answer (score 8):

Before I start explaining, let me note that `z-index` only has an affect if the element has *rendered* value of `position:relative`, `position:absolute`, or `position:fixed` (NOT `static`) because each of these make it have its own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). That means that values like `initial` or `inherit` may or may not work either depending on the situation.

Also note that in this post I'll be using the format 1.1.1 to signify that I am selecting the first element's first child's first child. 2.1.1 would be the second element's first child's first child and so on.

---

I think `z-index` is best explained with an analogy using sub lists. Let's start with the simplest example:

```
<div class="top-level"></div>
<div class="top-level sibling"></div>
```

We can represent this in terms of a list like so:

1. Top level
2. Top level sibling

Now by default the ones further down the list will render on top of the ones before it. So in this case 2 will be positioned on top of 1.

---

What z-index allows us to do is essentially reorder this list (within some bounds). The higher the z-index, the further down the list our element is.

I'll use inline CSS here to make showing it easy but you should *definitely* avoid inline CSS in production code.

```
<div class="top-level" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
<div class="top-level sibling"></div>
```

This now changes our sub listing to look like this:

1. Top level sibling
2. Top level - z-index:1

Great! Now the first element in our HTML will render on top of our second.

---

Where this gets more tricky is when we're dealing with children (nested) elements.

An easier way to think about this situation is to think that **when an element starts being rendered it will render all children of the element before moving onto any siblings**.

Also keep in mind that **sub-lists cannot change levels**, meaning they cannot be on the same level of their parent or their children elements.

That means that if we have the following:

```
<div class="top-level">
    <div class="sub-level" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
<div class="top-level sibling"></div>
```

Our rendering sub lists will look like the following:

1. Top level

   1. Sub level - z-index1
2. Top level sibling

Thus, we look our top level and see which one is at the bottom of the list. In this case, 2.0 is, so it will be on top of 1.0. Then we look and see if it has any sub lists (children). It doesn't, so we go to 1.0.

1.0 has a child, 1.1, which will be visually above 1.0 (just like it would be if we didn't give it a z-index), but it will still be below 2.0 because 1.0 is below 2.0.

Thus the z-index here doesn't help us out because 1.1 doesn't have any siblings.

---

Let's take a slightly more complex example:

```
<div class="top-level">
    <div class="sub-level" style="z-index: 2;"></div>
    <div class="sub-level sibling"></div>
    <div class="sub-level sibling" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
<div class="top-level sibling">
    <div class="sub-level"></div>
</div>
```

What's the sub listing for this example?

I'll give it to you, but it's good to try and do by yourself.

1. Top level

   1. Sub level sibling
   2. Sub level sibling - z-index1
   3. Sub level - z-index2
2. Top level sibling

   1. Sub level

Thus, in terms of what the order is visually from top to bottom, the order goes 2.1, 2.0, 1.3, 1.2. 1.1, 1.0.

That's not so bad, is it?

This behavior is true no matter how far deep or how many siblings are there.

---

The only exception to the rule that children are rendered above parents is when the children have a negative `z-index`. When a negative z-index is given, it places itself below a parent element.

Thus if we have the following:

```
<div class="top-level">
    <div class="sub-level" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
</div>
<div class="top-level sibling"></div>
```

The sub list tree would look like this:

1. Sub level - z-index-1

   1. Top level
2. Top level sibling

And the top to bottom layering would be 2.0, 1.0, 1.1.

A slightly more complex example:

```
<div class="top-level">
    <div class="sub-level" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
    <div class="sub-level sibling"></div>
</div>
<div class="top-level sibling"></div>
```

List representation:

1. Sub level - z-index-1

   1. Top level

      1. Sub level
2. Top level sibling

But you should **avoid negative `z-index`es**. If you think you need them it is likely that your HTML is structured improperly.

---

That's about it! If you're still interested in learning more, reading [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) is always good.

Keep in mind that [other properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), including but not limited to `opacity`, `transform`, and `will-change`, create their own stacking context and may have an affect on the rendering order of elements.

---

<sub>`opacity` works similarly to z-index - a child can only be as opaque as its parent - but it can't have negative values.</sub>

Comment: initial and inherit work just fine - the initial value is auto, and inherit is just one of those values you don't really ever use with z-index, but it *works*.

Answer (score 1):

The only exception to the rule that children are rendered above parents is when the children have a negative z-index. When a negative z-index is given, it places itself below a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

The css property `z-index` only works on positioned elements, meaning elements must be position absolute, fixed or relative in order for the `z-index` property to take effect.

The higher the z-index the closer to the front it will appear.  The values specified for the `z-index` property can be positive or negative.  A positioned element with a `z-index` value of 4 will appear above a positioned element with a `z-index` value of 3.

> In CSS 2.1, each box has a position in three dimensions. In addition
>   to their horizontal and vertical positions, boxes lie along a "z-axis"
>   and are formatted one on top of the other. Z-axis positions are
>   particularly relevant when boxes overlap visually.

Comment: "The higher the z-index the closer to the top it will appear." perhaps: "The higher the z-index the closer to the *front* it will appear." would be clearer.

Comment: According to the link in @JABFreeware's answer here, it says that it's not required for the element to be positioned for `z-index` to work! Is this true??

Comment: @FallintotheShadows I'm almost positive it needs to be positioned. See:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

Comment: @FallintotheShadows not sure how you got that from the linked article. It states (correctly): "z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative."

Comment: @steveax look here: `Although z-index is not a difficult property to understand, due to false assumptions it can cause confusion for beginning developers. This confusion occurs because z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative.`

Answer (score -1):

[This article on z-index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) is just the link you are looking for! He really explains it well.

Basically, the higher the number, the higher up on the stack the element will be. So 1 is on top of 0 and -1 is under the z-index of 0, however they should be kept positive, as there is no reason to use negatives; it's considered bad practice. The browser interprets it when it renders the page, like any other CSS or HTML code.

Comment: For it to work, it a `position` required to be set? Also, W3Schools gave negatives in it's examples... :) I think it's really time for me to start believing http://w3fools.com/! :)

Comment: @FallintotheShadows Yes you have to set the position property to either absolute, relative, or fixed. Basically anything except static, which is the value that the browsers use if its not set

Comment: But on the link your provided in your answer, it says it is not required to have a set `position`! It said that the default would work...

Comment: @FallintotheShadows Not in all browsers. Best to follow convention. Sorry to confuse you