# position fixed not working in mobile view in segments

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a segment (which does not contain any ion-content) and I want to add a footer kind of view item on the bottom. It works fine in the browser view, but not working for mobile view. Below is the attached screenshot for both the platforms.

[image: Here it's working fine, see the below comment box]
[image: But the section is not present here]
Here is the code snippet

```css
.comment-box-prop {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-box-prop">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-2>
      <img class="circle-pics" src="{{userAvatarUrl || Constants.IMGS_DEFAULT }}" alt="">
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-9>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="comment.CommentText" class="input-prop" type="text" placeholder="Write a comment"> </ion-input>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-1>
      <img src="assets/icons/icon_invite.svg" class="send-icon" name="send" (click)="sendMessage()">
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

Also if I remove the bottom property the comment box is appearing somewhere in the screen (not at the bottom obviously) but the bottom is not working in mobile view.

Comment: Have you tried to set a `z-index` to your `div.comment-box-prop` div?

Comment: I tried something like "z-index: 999" after seeing another post in stack overflow, But that didn't work. Also I'm not pretty sure about the functionality of z-index.

Comment: Here is a pretty good answer about z-index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391208/how-does-z-index-really-work ... Set a min-height to the `.comment-box-prop` to see if your element sticks to the footer.

Comment: Same problem, in mobile it's not working.