# My side navigation isn't going over the body content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue where my side nav (which appears on smaller screens) isn't going over the content of the body (text, pictures, etc). I have my z-index set to 500 for my side nav and 0 for my body content and that doesn't appear to resolve the issue which I thought it would).

Here is a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/timothykeyseraude/0w5wynLs/

```
html {
height: 100%
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Give z-index:1 to .navbar-header-foundation

Comment: @NiralMunjariya Thank you! that seemed to work! Thank you for all other recommendations!

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements, that is why you have to set z-index on your `navbar-header-foundation`, see more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391208/how-does-z-index-really-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add z-index:1 to "navbar-header-foundation" class, and your issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your using `position: absolute` on p tag... so take that off and that will fix your problem, if you want to center your text you can use `text-align: center`

Answer (score 0):

Put the side navigation outside of the header, the heasder is taking the z-index of its parent, the header. See below.

```js
// script.js


// ======= NavBar ======= //

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("side-navigation").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("side-navigation").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass";
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* jQuery */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}


/* ======= Background Image ======= */

body.home {
  background-image: URL("images/bc/Homebc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

body.about {
  background-image: URL("images/bc/Aboutbc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

body.approach {
  background-image: URL("images/bc/Approachbc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

body.contact {
  background-image: URL("images/bc/Contactbc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

body.tac {
  background-image: URL("images/bc/Termsbc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

body.privacy {
  background-image: URL("images/bc/Privacybc.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}


/* ======= NavBar ======= */

#body-content {
  z-index: 0;
}


/* --- top nav section --- */

.navbar-header-foundation {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #272727;
}

.top-navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #272727;
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-navigation li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
  height: 55px;
}

.top-navigation a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.top-navigation a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.top-navigation a.active {
  background-color: #52BA56;
}

.header__logo {
  float: right;
}

.brand__logo {
  height: 55px;
  width: 183px;
}


/* <> Top Nav Responsive Adjustments <> */

@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  .navbar-header-foundation {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #272727;
  }
  .brand__logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 167px;
  }
  .top-navigation {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .top-navigation li {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .top-navigation a {
    padding: 20px 50px;
  }
  .responsive__button {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}


/* --- side nav section --- */

.responsive__button {
  display: none;
}

.side-navigation {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: .85s;
  padding-top: 58px;
}

.side-navigation a:not(:first-child) {
  padding: 22px 10px 22px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.44s;
}

.side-navigation a:not(:first-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.side-navigation a:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.side-navigation a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.button-close-side-navigation {
  top: 9px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #52BA56;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .top-navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive__button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #52BA56;
    margin-left: 17px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.content-container {
  z-index: 0;
}

.content2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10ex;
  left:10em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="home" id="body-content">
  <section class="Navbar">
    <div id="NavBar-Navigation-Menu">
      <header class="navbar-header-foundation">
        <a href="#" class="header__icon" id="header__icon"></a>
        <a href="Index.html" class="header__logo" style="height: 0px">
          <img src="images/brandlogoNAV.png" class="brand__logo">
        </a>
        <nav class="top-navigation" id="top-navigation">
          <li><a class="active" href="Index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="Approach.html">OUR APPROACH</a></li>
          <li><a href="CONTACT.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </nav>
        <span class="responsive__button" onclick="openNav()">&#9776</span>
      </header>
       <nav class="side-navigation" id="side-navigation">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button-close-side-navigation" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <a href="Index.html">HOME</a>
          <a href="About.html">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="Approach.html">APPROACH</a>
          <a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="content-container">
      <p class="content2">
        aoefegfoyaefaerfuivba
        <br>
        <BR>bdiwubdiuwdwug
        <br>jwehdiuHFIUW
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
```