# How to scroll the body content with the side menu and make it dynamic for small screens?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

What should I do so that the content of the body is dynamic when hiding and showing the Side Menu? I am trying to create a product management project with PHP.

I have created a `Side Menu ( Sidebar )`, for which I used a template. The Side Menu also has a navigation bar that contains the button that we use to hide and show the Side Menu.

The new pages or views are added through `php`, and I want the content of the pages that I add new to occupy the entire screen, with a `margin-left: 40px` to the left and scroll dynamically when we show the Side Menu When I add a new page, two problems arise:

- The content of the new page is overlaid on top of the navigation bar and hidden under the Sidebar.

[See the screenshot](https://ibb.co/YLyZLfS)

I have fixed this problem first by adding `margin-top` and `margin-left`

```
.bodis {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 330px!important;
}
```

But this is not very dynamic and it is not Responsive either, since when I hide the Sidebar, the content of the pages stays in the center of the page and when the screen size is reduced, the content even disappears.

You can check it [in the first screenshot](https://ibb.co/LZbfYsk), . You can see that the content disappears when we reduce the size of the screen .
the content of the body remains in the center of the screen when we hide the Side Menu, [and in the second screenshot](https://ibb.co/866DFtM)

The template uses several frameworks for css and javascript that I show below. I have read the documentation of some of them, such as Bootstrap, but it is not clear to me what would be the best way to make the dynamic content for each of the screens that I add to the project

**Bootstrap V4.3**

**Bootstrap Material Design V4.0**

**Font Awesome V5.9.0**

**Sweet Alerts V8.13.0 CSS file**

**jQuery Custom Content Scroller V3.1.5**

------ javascript ----

**jQuery V3.4.1**

**popper**

**Bootstrap V4.3**

How can I make content dynamic and effective on mobile devices?

How can I make the content of the page occupy almost the entire screen and scroll when showing the Side Menu? Can I use any of the frameworks that the template uses?

I show the bar code of the Side Menu and that of One of the views, in this case the Home

**HOME VIEW:**

```
<div class="bodis">
  <div class="full-box page-header">
    <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
    <h2>BIENVENIDO ESTO ES EL HOME</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
<main class="full-box main-container">
  <section class="full-box nav-lateral">
    <div class="full-box nav-lateral-bg show-nav-lateral"></div>
    <div class="full-box nav-lateral-content">
      <figure class="full-box nav-lateral-avatar">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle show-nav-lateral"></i>
        <img src="./assets/avatar/Avatar.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Avatar">
        <figcaption class="roboto-medium text-center">
          Leading Company <br><small class="roboto-condensed-light">Panel Administración</small>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class="full-box nav-lateral-bar"></div>
      <nav class="full-box nav-lateral-menu">
        <ul>

          <li class="usuarioColor">
            <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu">
              <i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i>
              &nbsp; Usuarios
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?vista=user_new">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Añadir Usuario
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?vista=user_list">
                  <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Lista de Usuarios
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="index.php?vista=user_search">
                  <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Buscar
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>   
          <li class="productosColor">
            <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu">
              <i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-fw"></i>
              &nbsp; Productos <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Añadir Producto</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Lista de Productos</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Por Categoria
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-search-dollar fa-fw"></i>
                  &nbsp; Buscar
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="company.html"><i class="fas fa-store-alt fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Empresa</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Page content -->
  <section class=" full-box page-content">
    <nav class="fexid-top full-box navbar-info">
      <a href="#" class="float-left show-nav-lateral">
        <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-exit-system">
        <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </section>
</main>
```

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto_medium_regular';
    src: url('../webfonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../webfonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
    src: url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto_condensed_regular';
    src: url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

:root{
    --color-one: #F5F5F5;
    --color-two: #24292E;
    --color-three: #EC5252;
    /*--color-three: #0366D6;*/

    --form-color: #14111A;

    --accent-color: #253556;
    /*--accent-color: #455A64;*/
    --border-color: #D8D8D8;
}

.bodis {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 330px!important;
}

body,html{
    font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--color-one);
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.full-box{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-neon{
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/*----------  Page headers styles  ----------*/
.page-header{
    padding: 30px 20px 60px 20px;
}
.page-header > :nth-child(1){
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
.page-header > :nth-child(2){
    font-size: 18px;
}

/*----------  Page nav tabs  ----------*/
.page-nav-tabs{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.page-nav-tabs li,
.page-nav-tabs li a{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.page-nav-tabs li{
    margin: 5px 20px;
}
.page-nav-tabs li a{
    color: var(--accent-color);
    font-size: 17px;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.page-nav-tabs li a.active{
    color: var(--color-three);
    cursor: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.page-nav-tabs li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}

/*----------  Edit bootstrap styles  ----------*/
.form-control[readonly]{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.form-control:focus,
.form-control:active{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
.form-control-file:active,
.form-control-file:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.table .btn{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table thead th{
    color: #FFF;
}
.table tbody tr{
    color: #333;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.table-dark,
.table{
    background-color: #fff;
}
.table-dark{
    border: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
}
.table-dark thead tr{
    background-color: var(--accent-color);
}
.table-dark td,
.table-dark thead th,
.table-dark th{
    border: none;
}
.table-dark tr:hover{
    color: var(--color-three);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(124, 100, 112, .2) 85%, transparent);
}
.page-link{
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.page-link:hover{
    background-color: var(--color-three);
    color: #FFF;
}
table form{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/*----------  Text Styles  ----------*/
.roboto-medium{
    font-family: 'roboto_medium_regular';
}
.roboto-condensed-light{
    font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
}
.roboto-condensed-regular{
    font-family: 'roboto_condensed_regular';
}

/*----------  login Styles  ----------*/
.login-container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #0575E6;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #021B79, #0575E6);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #021B79, #0575E6);

}
.login-content{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: var(--accent-color);
}
.btn-login{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--accent-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.btn-login:hover{
    background-color: var(--color-three);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-three);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-login:active,
.btn-login:focus{
    outline: none;
}

/*----------  Page layout Styles  ----------*/
.main-container{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.page-content,
.nav-lateral{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.page-content{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 300px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/***********************/
/*  Nav Lateral */
/***********************/

/* COLORES DE LAS LISTAS */

/* nav > ul > li  a:hover {
    background: white !important;
    color:#47748b !important;
 } */
 .usuarioColor {
    background: rgb(239, 149, 54);
}


.nav-lateral{
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background-image: url('../assets/img/nav-font.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.nav-lateral-bg{ display: none; }
.nav-lateral-content{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(36, 41, 46, .8);
}
.nav-lateral-bar{
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--color-three);
}
.nav-lateral-avatar{
    padding: 40px 0;
}
.nav-lateral-avatar i{
    display: none;
}
.nav-lateral-avatar img{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.nav-lateral-avatar figcaption{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.nav-lateral-menu{
    height: auto;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li a.active{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: var(--color-three);
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 50%, transparent);
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li ul{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-three);
    background: rgba(20, 30, 48, .5);
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li ul a{
    padding-left: 45px;
}
.show-nav-lateral-submenu{
    display: block !important;
}
.nav-lateral-menu .fa-chevron-down,
.nav-lateral-menu .fa-chevron-up{
    float: right;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

/*  Page content */
.navbar-info{
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-info a{
    color: var(--accent-color);
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    user-select: none;
}
.navbar-info a:hover{
    color: var(--color-three);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle,rgba(250, 30, 78, .1), transparent 80%);
}
.navbar-info a:active,
.navbar-info a:focus{
    outline: none;
}

/*----------  Home Styles  ----------*/
.tile-container{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 25px;
}
.tile{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--accent-color);
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 3px;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.tile:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: var(--color-three);
}
.tile:focus,
.tile:active{
    outline: none;
}
.tile-tittle{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    font-family: 'roboto_medium_regular';
}
.tile:hover .tile-tittle{
    color: #FFF;
    border-color: var(--color-three);
    background-color: var(--color-three);
}
.tile-icon{
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 22px;
}
.tile-icon > i{
    font-size: 80px;
}
.tile-icon > p{
    font-family: 'roboto_medium_regular';
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.tile:hover .tile-icon > i,
.tile:hover .tile-icon > p{
    color: var(--color-three);
}


/*----------  Breakpoints  ----------*/
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .nav-lateral{
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none;
        background-image: none;
    }
    .nav-lateral.active{
        display: block;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .nav-lateral-bg{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, .4);
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .nav-lateral-content{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 3;
        transform: translateX(-400px);
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: var(--color-two);
    }
    .nav-lateral.active .nav-lateral-content{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    .nav-lateral-avatar i{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: #FFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }
    .nav-lateral-avatar i:hover{
        color: var(--color-three);
    }
    .page-content{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}


/*  Bootstrap breakpoints */
@media (min-width: 576px){

}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .nav-lateral.active{
        transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    .page-content.active{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){

}

@media (min-width: 1200px){

}

/*----------  Keyframes  ----------*/
```

I have tried to fix this error by adding `margin-top` and `margin-left` :

```
.bodis {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 330px!important;
}
```

But the result still does not meet the desired.
I have read [the bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/components/#responsive) trying to find a solution, but I don't see that it is the best for my needs

I have tried to implement [the answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635226/my-side-navigation-isnt-going-over-the-body-content), but it didn't work in my case

Comment: Change at first the body to 100% instead of 100vh or 100vw.

Comment: Do you mean the width...? I have several references in my code for the body, do I have to change in all the references that the body has 100%?

Comment: Here : **body,html{
    font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--color-one);
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
}**

Comment: Thanks, I have made this change, but it doesn't work. [You can see the result](https://ibb.co/GFZh4NM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem, and although I can't add all the code here, the solution was very simple.

I have only ordered my `css` files and removed what is not necessary, to avoid problems.

For views that are added back to my app, I put them inside two `div`.
The parent wraps everything and has the following css:

```
bodysuits {
    margin-top: 80px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width:100%;
}
.body .content {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

And we also add a second div with the `div class="content"`

In this way my different pages would look like this:

```
 <div class="bodis page-content">
   <div class="content">
     <h1 class="title ">Title</h1>
     <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
     
     <!-- THE REST OF THE CONTENT --!>
  
   </div>
</div>
```

Update the `media query` code by changing the width from `100%` to `300px` like so;

```
@media(max-width: 767px)
.nav-side-bg {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, .4);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

All this worked and I am encouraged to study css more intensely since I see that it is a very powerful language in web layout