# How to override a video on the top of a text in css?

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I am working on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hz8v4qc/34/embedded/result)

I want to override a video on the top of a text. The HTML code which I have used in order to make a video/text is:

```
<div class="player-elements">
  <div class="grid-stack">
    <iframe class ="video" width="800" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
  </div>   
</div>

<div class="hello-world" style="">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS so that the video gets on top of the `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing."` text.

I tried by adding `position:relative ,position:absolute and z-index` but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: are they under the same container?

Comment: also you need to set a `position` for both containers

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Yes they are in one div.

Comment: You just want the video to appear over the text? However in separate parent elements like the html example suggests and still using the iframe etc?

Comment: Yes I want to override the video over the text. If I didn't understand your 2nd point wrong, I don't want to alter the current html.

Comment: If you just set the z-index to a negative number on your `hello-world` div, it will not show on the screen...

Comment: @HereticMonkey How about if we have a full width text ? I just want the text to be behind the video. Can you give me a demo how to achieve that ?

Comment: You've got an answer that does that already...

Comment: @HereticMonkey This is what I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/1hz8v4qc/39/embedded/result

Comment: That appears to work when the screen is small enough that the video and text overlap. You have `bottom: 0` on your fixed position element, but your video is at the top, so on large screens, they don't overlap.

Comment: The parent container is kind of important here. Do you want these elements positioned relative to the parent container or to the page in general? `position:absolute` is actually positioned absolutely in the nearest ancestor with `position:relative`

Comment: very ugly description 
put hello word top of player ellement

Comment: @masoudsoroush I have modified my description. Can you have a look now ? Actually someone edited my question and I approved it accidentally.

Comment: @john like this ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/1hz8v4qc/42/embedded/result

Comment: @masoudsoroush text should go behind the video like we have the concept of z-index in css. I am not sure how I can implement properly in css.

Comment: @john so you want to fixed position for text but when scrolling text should be go behind the video right ?

Comment: @masoudsoroush The text position should be fixed and it should go behind the video.

Comment: @john Done give me a up vote dude :D

Comment: @masoudsoroush text is still on the top of a video. It should go behind the video. Only the words `Loren` and `Scing` and the rest of them should go back.

Answer (score 0):

css is a styling language not a markup language to build content
your problem comes from a css code already exists 
you can try to select to select positions for both of them absolute.

```
.grid-stack{
position: absolute;
}
.hello-world {
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each page is made up of a stack of elements. `z-index` is a way we can add a layer to that stack. In order to create another stack we have to **purposely** set the position to `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative`.

check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391208/how-does-z-index-really-work) for a more detailed response to this.

`z-index` values can be negative or positive but the default value is 0.

The different types of css `positions` are

> Relative. This type of positioning is probably the most confusing and
>   misused. What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set
>   position: relative; on an element but no other positioning attributes
>   (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at
>   all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position...
>
> Absolute. This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you
>   to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use
>   the positioning attributes top, left, bottom. and right to set the
>   location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next
>   parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning...
>
> Fixed. This type of positioning is fairly rare but certainly has its
>   uses. A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport,
>   or the browser window itself....

You can read more [Here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)

```css
.hello-world{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

.player-elements{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="player-elements">
       <div class="grid-stack">
         <iframe class ="video" width="800" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
      </div>   
   </div>

    <div class="hello-world" style="">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kNB3c/4179/) the snippet doesn't seem to run the youtube video.

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do the same thing here as you do on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense The html and css container names doesn't seem to match. Just checking, what are you trying to achieve with it ?

Comment: @john thanks for catching that, it was a copy paste error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with a brief description on why it  works and the role 'position:fixed` plays in it.

Comment: @JonP Thanks, I'll remember to do that next time as well.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to learn how work with spect element :D after that you can done your job even with try and catch

z-index for implant to element needs a position

so there as you can see its fixd
http://jsfiddle.net/1hz8v4qc/43/

```
.player-elements {
   z-index: 100;
   position:relative;
}

.hello-world 
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 80;
}
```

Good Luck